# Can't get in first gear on Shimano ten speed block

Tags: derailleur-rear

Just replaced drive chain on mtb ... new cassette (Shimano 10 sp ) new chain (Shimano 10sp) new rear mech (Shimano 10sp long) and new (Shimano 10sp). I've set bottom stop tensioned cable and adjusted the angle of the mech.

The gears shift perfectly until it gets to the first gear and it won't move into that gear. Back the stop off completely and still can't make the shift.... Any ideas ????

Begining to wonder if I should have spacer behind the cassette so the mech can make the shift .....

Comment: With the lower limit screw backed off, can you manually push the derailleur inboard far enough to get the chain onto the first gear sprocket.

Comment: IME you should only need a spacer if there is any looseness in the mounting of the cassette. when you shift into top gear, smallest cog, can you get a final, extra click, and a lot of slack in the cable?

Comment: Which cog will it not reach, the smallest or the largest?  If the smallest, is the cable slack when you try to reach it?

Comment: Hi .... I detached the cable and backed off the screw and with quite a bit of pressure (too much) it will go onto the large cog....  its as if the mech simply does not have the range of movement to make the shift ...

Comment: What cassette ratio are you using. Is the low gear number of teeth compatible with the rear derailleur? What do you mean by - 'I've adjusted the angle of the mech'?

Comment: Hi ... the cassette is 11-36 10 speed shimano and the rear mech is a long cage 10 speed shimano. As the angle adjustment its a little screw just near where the mech attaches to the frame that allows the mech to be moved back or forward top allow minmal distance between gears and top jockey wheel for good shifting.

Comment: Is your chain long enough? If not it may cause extra force being needed to get the chain into the largest casette gear